# Why is my mongoose array not beeing populated and doesn't even have values stored in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**The problem**

I know there are many similiar problems on Stack about this problem, but I wasn't able to solve it with these posts.

I'm creating a simple Forum application. I have 2 routes for creating a Forum and a Subforum. 
A Forum can have many Subforum's. 
A Subforum is assigned to one Forum.

**My Schema for Forum looks like this:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const forumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  subTitle: String,
  posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
  subForums: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Subforum" }]
});

const Forum = mongoose.model("Forum", forumSchema);

module.exports = Forum;
```

**The Schema for the Subforum:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const subForumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  subTitle: String,
  posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
  forum: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Forum" }
});

const SubForum = mongoose.model("Subforum", subForumSchema);

module.exports = SubForum;
```

If I create a new forum and save it I have it in the database. Of course with no Subforums yet.
**Then I create a Subforum like this (I provide the id of the just created forum with `req.body.forum`):**

```
router.post("/newSub", verify, async (req, res) => {
  // TODO: Only admin can do this
  const subForum = new SubForum({
    title: req.body.title,
    subTitle: req.body.subTitle,
    forum: req.body.forum
  });
  try {
    await subForum.save();
    res.send(subForum);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});
```

I get the response back that it has been created. The new Subforum looks like this:

[image]

But when I search for all forums and want to populate it with it's sub forums it won't work. In Robomongo it looks like this:

[image]

So you can clearly see that there is no subforum in the array.

**What is the problem and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you are actually pushing the `subforum` id to the `forum.subforum` array.  After you create your `subforum` and save it, you must also push that `subforum id` into the `forum.subforums` array and save that as well.

Comment: Thx that makes sense: So something like that: https://pastebin.com/KjDBB9s9

Comment: Thanks man. I somehow thought adding the forum id to the subforum is enough.